# Upload Pic(s) from blogger and showing them on blog created in Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony-1.4, image-upload

I have created a blog application with Symfony 1.4(ORM:Doctrine).
Bloggers can blog via backend only.I have also integrated TinyMCE for better formatting.

My question is how can a specific blogger upload image(s) to his blog,i.e., he can save the pic for a particular post (backend)and when the post is accessed by Viewers/Users(frontend)...the image is there alongside the post itself ??

Needless to say am a newbie...so please guide me :) !

Answer (score 0):

So just to be sure I understand your question
You want the blogger to be able to upload a picture, and then display this picture in your frontend along the post ?

You need to create a new field photo in your schema, in your post table, (a widgetFormInputFile) in order to then access it in your frontend

Comment: yes...thats what i was asking!..
ok..i'll give it a try and see how it figures out,btw can u point out some tutorials that do the same? Much Thanks!!

Comment: Just look the jobeet tutorial http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/12 look under "form views configuration" under "class"